# React + Chart.js 2.0: How to put a label inside of a doughnut chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am doing data visualizations with `react`, `react-chartjs-2`, and `chart.js` version 2.2.1. There is a possibly related answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966817/how-to-add-text-inside-the-doughnut-chart-using-chart-js) (look for 17.06.16 update), but I'm not sure what `Chart.pluginService.register` is or whether it is compatible with React. So far it hasn't worked for me.

I am simply looking to place a label inside the doughnut that is the sum of all `data` subsets. I assume this is nested somewhere in the [doughnut chart's options](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart), but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Negative. I had to make a separate value using the same data on my component

Comment: Please refer below code. This is perfectly work.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54040320/pass-context-to-options-on-react-chartjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54040320/pass-context-to-options-on-react-chartjs-2)

Answer (score 5):

In `react-chartjs-2` you can access the datasets through `chart.config.data.datasets`.

So for:

```
data = {
    labels: [
        'Red',
        'Green',
        'Yellow'
    ],
    datasets: [{
        data: [300, 50, 100],
    ...
```

Inside the `draw` callback in `Chart.helpers.extend` you can use:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < this.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
   sum += this.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[i];
}
```

Here's an example Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqMQQB?editors=1010