# Pass context to options on React ChartJS 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm using React ChartJS 2 to create some graphs but I want to show a label in top of them with the percentage and when I hover over them the real number. I found you can do something like this using the context on the options object.

```
var options = {
   tooltips: {
     enabled: false
   },
   plugins: {
     datalabels: {
       formatter: (value, ctx) => {

         let datasets = ctx.chart.data.datasets;

         if (datasets.indexOf(ctx.dataset) === datasets.length - 1) {
           let sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
           let percentage = Math.round((value / sum) * 100) + '%';
           return percentage;
         } else {
           return percentage;
         }
       },
       color: '#fff',
     }
   }
 };

var ctx = document.getElementById("pie-chart").getContext('2d');
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'pie',
   data: {
     datasets: data
   },
   options: options
 });
```

Like this, but my problem is that I cannot get a way to use the context inside the options.

Does someone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to manually pass the `context` to the datalabels' `formatter` function since the plugin takes care of this itself.

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/01120zp0jv) of the pie graph with the options specified above.

But if you want to access the chart's `context` in some other functions you want to pass to the `options`, then you can get it through the chart instance by using `this.chart.ctx`.

```
var options = {
  animation: {
    onComplete: function () {
      var chartInstance = this.chart;
      var ctx = chartInstance.ctx; // chart context
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!