# How to display data on hover inside doughnut chart in Angular Chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

Hi how to display data on hover inside doughnut chart using  [Angular Chart](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: what is that you have  done in the code? update it to post.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the answer of Alesana from this:

[How to add text inside the doughnut chart using Chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966817/how-to-add-text-inside-the-doughnut-chart-using-chart-js)

and register an additional plugin service:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeTooltipDraw: function(chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.elements.center) {
        if (chart.tooltip._active && chart.tooltip._active.length > 0) {
            chart.config.options.elements.center.text = 
                chart.tooltip._active[0]._view.label + ':' + chart.tooltip._data.datasets[0].data[chart.tooltip._active[0]._index];
        }
    }
  }
});
```

For the chart, you may also want to put:

```
options: {
    tooltips: { enabled: false }
}
```

I know that it may not be a good idea to use _view, _data, etc. Please correct this to a better way to access the label and dataset values.