# Chart.js with slider bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js, sliders

Trying to include slider bars with Chart.js. I tried to follow the code the     [sgrillion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966817/how-to-add-text-inside-the-doughnut-chart-using-chart-js) posted but could not get it to work properly. I also wanted to add tooltip to slider handle. Is there another way of accomplishing this without   loosing the text or data from each slider? Here is the code and the results:
    The sample code is on [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wp4f693/2/): I used 
    jquery-ui.css
    jquery-1.10.js
    jquery-ui.js
    Chary.js
        [image]

```
index

<div class="titre">Coffee:</div>
    <div id="red"></div>
    <div class="titre">Bun:</div>
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div class="titre">Cake:</div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div class="titre">Tea:</div>
    <div id="yellow"></div>
    <div class="titre">Water:</div>
    <div id="sienna"></div>
    <div class="titre">Donut:</div>
    <div id="gold"></div>
    <div class="titre">Spaghetti:</div>
    <div id="violet"></div>

 <canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
```

I would like to end up with something closer to this:
  [image]

Comment: What is the problem? The link you shared (https://jsfiddle.net/9wp4f693/2/) looks exactly as the image you included. Also tooltips are fine.    
    
The only thing missing is tooltip at slider handle. Is that it then?