# How can I add some text in the middle of a half doughnut chart in Chart.JS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

It should look somehow like this:

I already have the chart, just the text is missing. Is there an option to get the text in the middle of the chart?

EDIT: An example of such a graph can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/wt4260qf/1/

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
        circumference: 1 * Math.PI
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: You could use the [Title](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html) attribute

Comment: @DTul: Sure, but this will add the title `above` the chart. See https://jsfiddle.net/5mty0z32/.

Comment: @DTul You're right... I should have read the documentation more precisely.Of course, there is `position: 'bottom'`.

Comment: @FranzHuber23 **FYI:** [You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: @baburao: Good to know. Was worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@DTul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8731503/dtul), I figured it out. The title configuration is here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html.

I've added the following section:

```
title: {
   display: true,
   text: 'Custom Chart Title',
   position: 'bottom'
}
```

to the `options`.

The whole example looks now like that:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
        circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
        title: {
           display: true,
           text: 'Custom Chart Title',
           position: 'bottom'
        }
     }
});
```

The corresponding fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ktq8mb0z/

Answer (score 1):

I used this instructions

[How can I add some text in the middle of a half doughnut chart in Chart.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459077/how-can-i-add-some-text-in-the-middle-of-a-half-doughnut-chart-in-chart-js)

some changes for text position and fontsize

```
var fontSizeToUse = 16;
var centerY = ((chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) - 80);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vencendor/e0c8rgbm/

Comment: This looks really good. What can I do to not have a fixed `80` for the offset but calculate this on basis of the available space? (E.g. reduce it dynamically from 80 to 20 or so if the chart gets scrolled smaller).

Answer (score 0):

half-doughnut,  or how I call it, a speedometer graph, is now configured with degrees:

```js
var chart = new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: ['400', '200'],
  options: {
    rotation: -90,
    circumference: 180,
}
```

I did this in Chartjs version 3.5.1