# Add Text to Doughnut Chart - ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I have charts

```
<div class="col-xs-2"><canvas id="device"></canvas></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><canvas id="host_name"></canvas></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><canvas id="city"></canvas></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><canvas id="org"></canvas></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><canvas id="country"></canvas></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><canvas id="region"></canvas></div>
```

[image]

---

## CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .chart-inner {
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
    .chart-inner h5 {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-top: 27px;
        font-size: 200px;
        color: red;
    }

</style>
```

---

I've tried to append text to the center

```
$('canvas#' + selector).append('<div class="chart-inner"><h5>' + selector + '</h5></div>');
```

It doesn't seem to come through.

---

But when I hide(), it works. All charts are hidden.

```
$('canvas#' + selector).hide();
```

What am I missing ?

---

## Updated

```
<script>

    function renderChart(selector, chartType, colors, labels, values, chartLine ) {


        let chart = document.getElementById(selector).getContext('2d');

        new Chart(chart, {
            type:chartType, // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
            data:{
                labels:labels,
                datasets:[{
                    data:values,
                    // backgroundColor:colors,
                    backgroundColor:colors,
                    borderWidth:1,
                    borderColor:'white',
                    hoverBorderWidth:2,
                    hoverBorderColor:colors,
                    hoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    borderAlign: 'inner',
                }]
            },
            options:{
                title:{
                    display:true,
                    text:selector
                },
                legend:{
                    display:false,
                    position:'right',
                    labels:{
                        fontColor:'#000'
                    }
                },
                cutoutPercentage: 70,
                animation:{
                    animateScale:true,
                },
            }
        });


        // $('canvas#' + selector).append('<div class="chart-inner"><h5>' + selector + '</h5></div>');
        // $('canvas#' + selector).hide();
        //$('canvas#device').append('<div class="chart-inner"><h5>1234</h5></div>');
    }

    /*=========================================
    =            deviceType            =
    =========================================*/

    var ajax = $.ajax({url: '/visitor/summary/device'});
    ajax.done(function (response) {

        deviceTypeLabels = [];
        deviceTypeValues = [];

        $.each(response, function(key,val) {
            deviceTypeLabels.push(key);
            deviceTypeValues.push(val);
        });

        renderChart('device', 'doughnut', colors, deviceTypeLabels, deviceTypeValues );

    });

    ... and more charts ...  


</script>
```

Comment: is this similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966817/how-to-add-text-inside-the-doughnut-chart-using-chart-js?

Comment: "It doesn't seem to come through" : is it correctly added to the code source, or is it simply not showing where you want ?

Comment: Show me `selector` please

Comment: can you post your chart method params please?

Comment: @vincent-d I added more charts codes on the post. What do you mean selector ?

Comment: your variable `selector`, what does it contains, how is it made? for the chart code, what I wanted is to reproduce :) any chance to have a fiddle?

Comment: It got pass in as the first argument of this `renderChart('device', 'doughnut', colors, deviceTypeLabels, deviceTypeValues );` in an ajax fn(). Imaginge that happening 5 times ...

Comment: Ex. in that case above selector = `device `

Comment: Could this just be a z-index issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've tried to append text to the center

You're appending elements inside of the `canvas` tag. [That's only displayed as a fallback when your browser lacks canvas support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#Usage_notes).

What you're looking for is using the canvas `getContext` method.

[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/m8crtsk7/)

Adapted to what you provided, it would go something like this:

```
var centerX = chart.width / 2;
var centerY = chart.height / 2;

chart.fillStyle = 'black';
chart.font = '200px';
chart.textAlign = 'center';
chart.fillText(selector, centerX, centerY);
```

You may need to offset centerX or centerY depending on how the width of your doughnut charts is calculated.